# Typescript NodeJs debugging no source maps usable

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, intellij-idea, ts-node

I use **ts-node** to transpile the typescript code. When i try to debug in IntelliJ the first ts files can be seen correctly, but then i step into the transpiled javascript code. I added ?`import 'source-map-support/register'` to the entry-file.

[image]

This is what i call from package.json:

`TS_NODE_PROJECT=tsconfig.setup-e2e.json node --inspect --require ts-node/register apps/setup-e2e/src/app.ts`

I do not find source maps anywhere. Somehow Intellij shows some ts files and the rest as transpiled javascript:

[image]

Are the source maps maybe just created in memory and i have to reference them from IntelliJ?

How can i debug all the typescript source files?

Comment: I somehow works now. I moved it to a separate folder instead with the other projects in a monorepo and installed the packages separately. This is used to start the application: `node -r ts-node/register src/app.ts`